# Send error to parent from child using Fork

Tags: node.js, fork, fork-join

I have the below code

```
// Parent.js

var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('./pChild.js');

child.on('message', function(m) {
    // Receive results from child process
    console.log('received: ' + m);
});

// Send child process some work
child.send('First Fun');
```

```
// pChild.js

process.on('message', function(m) {
console.log("Helloooooooooo from pChild.js")
// Pass results back to parent process
process.send("Fun1 complete");
});
```

How to handle error in parent thrown from pChild.js and kill the process?

Comment: What about `child.on('exit', callback);` and throw/send from `pchild.js` ?

Comment: @Amol M Kulkarni Plz check my last comment below and provide me with some suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unhandled errors in the child process will cause it to exit, which will emit the [`'exit'` event](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error) on the `child` object.

```
child.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
    console.log('Child exited:', code, signal);
});
```

If the error is handled within the child, it can be sent as another message:

```
// in pChild.js
/* ... */.on('error', function (error) {
    process.send({ error: error.message || error });
});
```

#### Updated answer

On child

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    process.send({isError: true});
});
```

On master

```
 master.on('message',({isError, data})=>{
    if(isError) {
         master.kill('SIGINT');
         return;
    }
    console.log('message from child', data);
    master.kill('SIGINT');
 });
```

Comment: Error is handled in child process process.on('message', function(m) {
console.log("Helloooooooooo from pChild.js")
    var a = -5;
    if (a == -5)
        throw new Error('****id must be positive')
    // Pass results back to parent process
    process.send("Fun1 complete");
}); The parent should know which process failed and simultaneously all the pending child process has to killed

Comment: @user87267867 Well, that snippet doesn't show how the error is handled. Just how it's thrown. A `try...catch` or `.on('error', ...)` binding would be needed to handle it. Otherwise, the `'exit'` event should be emitted within the parent.

Comment: Yet the error is not getting handled in parent process.on('message', function(m) {
console.log("Helloooooooooo from pChild.js")
    var a = -5;
    if (a == -5)
        throw new Error('****id must be positive')
    // Pass results back to parent process
    process.send("Fun1 complete");
}).on('error', function (error) {
    process.send({ error: error.message || error });
});